# Power amplifier - unexpected Bode plot

Tags: power, amplifier

I designed this schematic for a power amplifier project at university.

The problem with it is the Bode plot, because as you can see on the Y-axis, it doesn't even reach 0 dB and frequencies reach up to 1 Terahertz.

I've been at it for 3 days, scouring the internet for information, so this is my last resort.

UPDATE:So i recallculated the resistor values aslo changed some transistors.
And the is the rusulting bode plot.It still does not meet my requerments(fb 25 Hz fh 25kHz).Maybe I am mising some capacitors or the gain is to high?
[image: Bode plot][image: schematic]
[image]

Comment: Is there anybody who thinks something is wrong with Q6 ??

Comment: Looks like V3 has the wrong polarity

Comment: @ muyustan - I don't think so.  Q6+R6+D5+R7 form a constant current source, which is used to forward bias the crossover distortion elimination diodes D1-D4.

Comment: @glen_geek - Right!  That would cause the circuit to not work, but I don't think that would affect the bode plot

Comment: Have you actually tried what @glen_geek said? I think you might be surprised.

Comment: I will not say anything about the wrong parts of the circuit as the other guys have already pointed them out. Anyway, placing a few tens or hundreds of picofarads across C-B of Q5 will bring you a high end. It's called Miller Capacitance.

Comment: Before worrying about the Bode plot you **must** make sure that all the transistors are biased properly. So do a DC Operating point simulation. Yes, just one point. Check that all the currents and voltages make sense. Only if that is all what it should you run an AC simulation to get a Bode plot. You would not be the first person to simulate **crap** because the circuit isn't biased properly. I know you didn't check because V3 is indeed upside down.

Comment: @SteveSh - Of course the wrong polarity of V3 will affect the bode plot, because the operating point will be wrong and therefore the amplifier will not work as intended.

Comment: V3 polarity is definitely wrong. You have two positive 30V supplies attached now, it makes no sense.

Comment: After that R3,R4 are too small and reduces hFE and peak power too much and R1, R2 can be reduced to Rce(sat)=1.3V/5A = 0.26 approx. 50% of 2W

Comment: @Hufi - But you can compute the bode plot without knowing anything about the voltage levels.  All you need are the appropriate transfer functions.

Comment: @SteveSh - the problem is that the small signal transfer functions depend on the operating point of the circuit. This is the reason why the simulation tools first compute the DC operating points before they compute the AC behavior. The AC behavior is the behavior of the circuit *linearized about its DC operating point*.

Comment: Looks like you BOTH flipped V3 upside down AND changed the voltage to negative 30 V. You ended up with the same circuit.

Comment: I am suspicious about R5 as it seems likely to remove most of the Vas gain, and with R8 calling for a stupid amount of gain from the thing....

Comment: Is there any reason you would want such a high amplification? Your feedback resistors seem to be `R8` and `R9`, and the gain is 801 (58 dB). I might be wrong, but it looks like `R3` and `R4` are not connected properly? It could be that OrCAD doesn't draw the dots on the pins. Also, for 30 V supply, `R1` and `R2` seem too high, and those 4 diodes might not be proper. This is a basic design, but the reason you see THz is because this is SPICE, there are no parasitics, no PCB, no imperfections, just the "run" button.

Comment: I calculated R1 and R2 to be 0.37 ohms but the requirement is standard resistor values. The closest one is 1 ohm. I will recalculate all resistor values and update maybe I misscalculated them.

Comment: @Mixera4 The closest values are 0.33 and 0.47 for 10% tolerance. See [this](http://logwell.com/tech/components/resistor_values.html) for a list of values.

Answer (score 0):

You have a direct capacitive_coupled path from input to output, thru the junction capacitances of the transistors.

opps Forgot about the 0.47 ohm of R1. Darn